# QGis 3.0 Multiuser Access

Tags: qgis-3, editing

How does multiuser access work in QGis 3.0?

Can multiple people open and edit the same object in a layer and save it at the same time? (Edit: Yes, but it may cause loss of data) 
Does it warn you before overwriting or does it update automatically after someone edits it? (Edit: No) 
I am using shapefile data at the moment.
Does it work with that or do I have to set up a database-server? 
If yes, how can I do so?

### Main goals of the database:

- all users have read/wirite access
- data edited by multiple users at the same time gives the second user a notification/warning before saving

Comment: You had tagged PostGIS but do not mention that you have tried using that or what you have tried with it, and so I have removed it.  Likewise with PostgreSQL and Windows 10.  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-user access can work in three ways:

1. By using Postgres and PostGIS where you can write SQL queries like:

**CREATE ROLE "whatever you wanna name"
VALID UNTIL 'infinity';**

or in pgadmin when you will connect your database downside the panel there is the option of login roles where you can right click and create a login role and give him privileges whether you want him to update or select the data or whatsoever.
Later you can connect the layer in QGIS and work.

2. The use of geoserver. 
   Launch QGIS and add the WFS server.
3. User Profile Management in QGIS.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/7b92f1f1e445e069db0a6fb454318ad789c98778

The user profile contains information about the user profile organisers. The management tools can be accessed from the Settings menu under User Profiles.

Comment: What happens with PostGis and Postgres if multiple people change the same object and save? In Excel f.e. it warns you at saving and shows overlapping changes.
WIthout additional software in QGis the last save delets changes of the saves before in the meantime.

Is there a detailed tutorial for beginners to set up a PostGis server and link it to QGis? I am not experienced in this topic at all.
A recommendation of version and settings would help a lot aswell.
Also what type of data will the server use? We currently use shapefiles.

Comment: @Rubedo  If multiple people change the same object and save them such objects are shown up in red and they are correspondingly labelled with the username. For more reference, you can check this: https://github.com/sourcepole/pgversion  I am currently using PostgreSQL 9.5,PostGIS 2.2 and pgrouting 2.1.0 Yes shapefiles can be easily uploaded in the database too just remember you have to install a plugin in pgadmin named: PostGIS shapefile and dbf loader and yes make sure you fill up the SRID columns coz they don't read the .prj files. For the SRID part, you can use the site:prj2espg.org/search

Comment: @Rubedo Regarding making the connection you can check this link https://opengisgal.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/tutorial-creating-a-postgis-database-for-qgis-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Not a specialist of multi-user access but as far as I know it's not QGis but your data provider that allow it or not and determine how it's handled.

If you are using shapefile my understanding is that only the first person who access it has full right on it, all other user will get read-only access to the data.

If you need full right (create, edit, delete...) for simultaneous user you need to use a database that allow this setup (and configure the behavior when simultaneous edit have been made to the same object)

Answer (score -1):

One of the best way to have multiuser access for QGIS 3 is to use a PostgreSQL database and the PostGIS plugin. It can be setup on premise or in the cloud with a VPS. This would allow simultaneous work on the same project down to the feature level.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: Great tip. Thank you!